# How to transform a String containing XML tags into a XML document

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have a String containing the following:

```
"<CV-ALL><CURRICULO-VITAE SISTEMA-ORIGEM-XML='DEGOIS_ONLINE' DATA-ATUALIZACAO='26032015' HORA-ATUALIZACAO='193918' VERSAO-DA-GRAMATICA='2.0'><DADOS-GERAIS NOME-COMPLETO='Gonçalves' NOME-EM-CITACOES-BIBLIOGRAFICAS='Pte, A.' NACIONALIDADE='P' CURRICULUM-CONCLUIDO='SIM' OUTRAS-INFORMACOES-RELEVANTES='' ID-DEGOIS='267296113190873275' ORCID='0000-0001-5944-3218'><ENDERECO FLAG-DE-PREFERENCIA='ENDERECO_INSTITUCIONAL'><ENDERECO-PROFISSIONAL CODIGO-INSTITUICAO-EMPRESA='1124000002312' NOME-INSTITUICAO-EMPRESA='Instituto Politécnico' CODIGO-ORGAO='43400884' NOME-ORGAO='Escola Superior' CODIGO-UNIDADE='11241886' NOME-UNIDADE='Centro de Investigação' PAIS='Portugal' UF='CE'/> .... "
```

Please, note that for the sake of simplicity I have omitted the the remaining content of this string and its content is in fact an XML document.

Anybody knows/has an XSL transformation script that takes as input a string such this and transform it to a document XML so that it is possible to navigate using XPath expressions?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you using for transformation? A string like that cannot exist inside an XML document unless it is a `CDATA` section. Is it a string in another programming language? If so, which one?

Comment: XSLT is meant to take an XML document and turn it into something else (using XPath etc).  You need to make this be an XML document first, using .. well, just about anything that can process plain text.

Comment: The question starts "I have a String" ... in what language do you have a string? Java? C#? Javascript? Other? The entire question is missing the whole context by which anyone can answer. No one can guess in what language you have this "string" and therefore no one can suggest how you can make that string into an XMl Document (which, in itself is also meaningless unless we know which programming language).

Comment: The string I mentioned is the text of an element node. Then my question is how can transform this text, which contains in fact XML tags, in a XML document so that it is possible to navigate on it using XPath expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are passing the string to the XSLT stylesheet as a parameter, and processing a dummy XML document, you have two options:

1. Output the string with output escaping disabled, save the result
   as a new document, then process the new document with another
   XSLT stylesheet;
2. Use XSLT 3.0 (or a processor that supports parsing XML as an
   extension) to parse the string as XML before processing it.

Of course, you could save yourself all this trouble by writing the string to a file using your parent process, then pointing your XSLT processor to the resulting file.

Comment: Yes, the string containing XML tags is passed to the XSLT stylesheet as a parameter. I have no access to hard disc from the XSD document, which has to process this string and produce as output an XML document on which I can navigate using XPath. Then the transformation from the content of this string to XML document must be done only in the XSLT stylesheet. I am wondering if there is an XSLT transformation script that iterates an string, analysing it, and that produces an XML document.

Comment: I would advise against trying to parse XML using XSLT string tools, because ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3016153

Comment: @rzfrantz Is this question not answered? If not, why not?

Comment: I've written a transformation with scaping desabled (following option 1 above) and the result was a new XML document. The problem was solved. Thanks!